# Combine 2 text files into one file using python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

'''
Hello Guys,
I have 2 text files.

```
file1.txt
1154 1353 G6 
1354 1408 G2 
1409 1592 G3 
1593 1729 G6 


file2 .txt
G1 =1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
G2 =0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
G3 =0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
G4 =0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
G5 =0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
G6 =0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want a final text file which is the combination of both files.

```
file3.txt

1154 1353 G6 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1354 1408 G2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1409 1592 G3 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1593 1729 G6 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If you kindly help me how to do, I will be very thankful.
'''

Comment: Have you tried to tackle the problem yourself, any code you have tried ?

Comment: [This website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/) helps you how to read and write a text file using python. Just check it and create a simple algorithm yourself. Its not a big stuff.

Comment: Here is the solution: ```with open('1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('2.txt','r') as f2,open('3.txt', 'w') as f3:
    f1Lines = [x[:-1] if '\n' in x else x for x in f1.readlines()]
    f2Lines = [x[:-1] if '\n' in x else x for x in f2.readlines()]
    [f3.writelines(i+j.split("=")[1]+'\n') for i in f1Lines for j in f2Lines if i[-2]==j[1]]
f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()```

Comment: @debajyoti Arrange and use it

Comment: @debajyoti Or raise a same new question and I will answer on that question.

Comment: @SamuelMiddendorp I tried " join " using ubuntu. But not gettign proper result.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
F1 = open("1.txt","r")
a = ((F1.read()).split("\n"))
a_list = []
for i in a:
    i=i.strip()
    a_list.append(i.split(" "))

F2= open("2.txt","r")
b = ((F2.read()).split("\n"))

b_list = []
for i in b:
    i = i.replace("=",'')
    i = i.strip()
    b_list.append(i.split(" "))

combined_list = []

for i in a_list:
    for j in b_list:
        if i[-1] == j[0]:
            combined_list .append(i + j[1:])

write_str=""
for i in combined_list:
    write_str += ' '.join(map(str, i))
    write_str += '\n'

F3 = open("3.txt","w")
F3.write(write_str)
```

Comment: That is nothing like what OP wants...

Comment: Thank you so much. It is really helpful for me. :)

Comment: @debajyoti happy to hear that :) Please accept/upvote the answer if it was helpful :)